# How to run a function when input has filled in

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using QuaggaJS for scanning barcodes, the barcode I return in a input field. How can I run a function when Quagga put's a barcode in my input?

Onchange & Oninput

```
<input oninput="alert_success()" class="form-control" id="bnummer" type="text" name="Bnummer" value="" style="width: 280px" required><br/>
```

That I can run a function when Quagga puts a barcode in my input field

I've now placed an alert where Quagga detect my barcode, this works fine on my PC but on my smartphone is doesn't work.....

```
Quagga.onDetected(function(result) {
        var code = result.codeResult.code;

        document.getElementById("bnummer").value = code;

        alert('Test');
});
```

Comment: It's worth checking to see if your library fires a change event on the input, if so, it would be easy to listen for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detecting programmatic changes to a form control's value is usually more trouble then it is worth.

Instead, use the `Quagga.onDetected(callback)` method (where `callback` is your function) as described [in the documentation](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/).